# When $25$ is added to a number and the result is halved , the answer is $3$ times the original number. What is the number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

When $25$ is added to a number and the result is halved , the answer is $3$ times the original number. What is the number ?

Comment: Show how you'd approach the problem, so we know why you can't do it yourself, and where you need more comprehension.

Comment: $\phantom{}$ $$\large{5}$$

Comment: That's the equation $(x+25)/2=3x$.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to solve
$$\frac{x+25}{2}=3x $$

Answer (score 2):

You could just start at $1$, see if it works, and if it doesn't, just keep incrementing until you hit a number that works. Hopefully it's not some ridiculously large number like $10^{100} + 1$.

There's a better way: <s>you've got the equation and you just need to solve for x. Multiply both sides by 2 to get 50 + 2x = 6x. Then 2x = 60x - 50. And then x = 30x - 25. Oops, I took a wrong turn somewhere. Let me back up to 50 + 2x = 6x.</s>

On a sheet of graphing paper, or on a graphing calculator, plot $$\frac{25 + x}{2}.$$ On that same sheet or screen, also plot $3x$. Where the twain meet be yar answer, lad or lass.

Comment: Thank u , I got the answer from your equation and all others thank u for the right equation , I got my answer ..

Comment: First cross multiplication needed

Comment: Sorry, you need to back up further... `Multiply both sides by 2 to get
50+2x=6x.` is already wrong. And why in the end use graphing when you can simply solve the equation (in your case if 50+2x=6x then subtract 2x from both sides so 50=4x, then divide both sides by 4 so x=12.5) ?

Comment: You're right, @hertitu. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Sorry brothers , it's answer is 5 written in answer key of my maths book .. BTW equation is right , there all I need is first   first cross multiplication and after that x wil go to other side as it was first in + and then - and then division we get 5 answer ...